# How can i generate java code from OWL file in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, owl, protege

There is my probleme, i have OWL file that i generated from Protege, and now from this OWL file i need to generate his java code in intellij. I tried to use jena in intellij but it seems not working for me, so Any solutions ?

Comment: what kind of Java code do you expect based on an OWL file? What is the code supposed to do? What did you try with Jena? And what did not work?

Comment: By the way *"not working"* is a meaningless description of a problem ...

Comment: Do you wish to load the file with Java code using the Jena API, or by 'generate' you mean something like creating Java classes with the same names as the classes in the OWL file? If you want to load the file with Jena, the tutorials here work for IntelliJ or any other IDE: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/